# Puppeteer: Can I tell the web-server to not send resources?

Tags: c#, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I know that I can intercept the requests and exclude processing of certain types of resources: images, media, etc. As far as I understand, this only reduces work on my local machine.

```
var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(options, null);
var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();

...

await page.SetRequestInterceptionAsync(true);
page.Request += (sender, e) => {
    switch (e.Request.ResourceType) {
        case ResourceType.Image:
        case ResourceType.ImageSet:
        case ResourceType.Media:
        case ResourceType.Font:
            e.Request.AbortAsync();
            break;
        default:
            e.Request.ContinueAsync();
            break;
    }
};
```

Is there a way to somehow tell the server not to waste time preparing these resources so that the answer comes to me earlier?

Just for context, here's an example of how I navigate to a page and want to speed up the process:

```
var url = "https://...";
var timeout = 100000;

var response = await page.GoToAsync(url, timeout, 
    new WaitUntilNavigation[] { WaitUntilNavigation.Networkidle2 }
);
```

Comment: Aborting requests actually stops the whole thing--it's blocked before it leaves your machine and never touches the server. It's always a good idea to share an actual example, though, since there may be all kinds of ways to optimize it.

Comment: Based on your edit, NetworkIdle2 is a very slow, strict load condition that [is often overkill for most cases](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#never-using-domcontentloaded), which is why it's labeled as "DISCOURAGED" in the docs. If you're just trying to get a certain piece of data on the page, use DOMContentLoaded. Can you share a complete example, page and your desired result, so it's easier to advise and provide specific optimizations?

Answer (score 1):

If you have control in server side,you can design a couple of RESTful APIs. Then you'll send json data and receive json data.

If you don't, you may try http [Accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) header. e.g `Accept: text/*`

Reference:

- [How do I set multiple custom HTTP headers in puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63062387/11226492)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types

Comment: This seems unrelated to OP's question, although they should clarify their use case.

Comment: @ggorlen Oh, I'm not familiar puppeteer, puppeteer may have some options or code to not make request of imgs/fonts/... .e.g the user of puppeteer can control their request work flow,they tell puppeteer to fetch html, css, js, but not to fecth media resources. But I don't know that, and I think `Accept` header will indicate the web server not to send some types of resource to client. In a particular situation,if the web server send, the client will refuse it at the beginning of receive phase.

Comment: OP is already blocking requests so they never even leave their local machine.

Comment: @ggorlen So, OP was misunderstood the code, and he steps into a wrong way.